# Cache control in JBoss 7

Tags: deployment, jboss7.x, cache-control

In JBoss 5, I have cache control configured in web.xml.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CacheControlFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
     <param-name>Cache-Control</param-name>
     <param-value>max-age=3600</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CacheControlFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CacheControlFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But when I try to deploy the war to JBoss 7. It failed because the filter is gone. Is there an equivalent class in JBoss 7 to replace org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter?

Thanks

In other word, how cache control is handled in JBoss 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the jbossweb-service.jar from

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjbosswebservicejar.htm

But I'm still wondering why it's not in JBoss 7.